# AngularJS: detailview updates the model on every change

Tags: angularjs

I show a modal with a detailview when a user wants to edit a specific item. The detailview has several fields binded to the model. This is an example for one of them:

```
   <input type="text" ng-model="task.title">
```

The issue is that when I bind the input to the model's field the field is changed immediately. Even if the user cancels the modal the field will remain changed. I thought of cloning the item's JSON and saving it when "save" is clicked:

```
$scope.saveTask = function (task) {
    console.log('task save ->', task);

    for(var i in $scope.selectedTask) {
        if ($scope.selectedTask.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            $scope.selectedTask[i] = task[i];
        }
    }

    dataLayer.saveTask(task);
};

$scope.$on('showTaskDetails', function (event, task) {
    console.log('task ->', task);

    $scope.selectedTask = task;
    $scope.show_modal = true;

    $scope.task = _.cloneDeep(task);
});
```

I feel there is a better way. Is there a better way?